# Cypress wait-until not working as expected

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm using the [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until) plugin. I have a HTML test page with long scroll and element on bottom. A simple script scrolls the element into view. I have a Cypress test which checks if an element appears within the viewport, but it isn't working as expected:

```
.waitUntil(() => cy.get('#scrollTo').isInViewport());
```

With cypress command `isInViewport`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isInViewport', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  const windowInnerWidth = Cypress.config('viewportWidth');
  const windowInnerHeight = Cypress.config('viewportHeight');

  const bounding = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  const rightBoundOfWindow = windowInnerWidth;
  const bottomBoundOfWindow = windowInnerHeight;

  expect(bounding.top).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.left).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.right).to.be.lessThan(rightBoundOfWindow);
  expect(bounding.bottom).to.be.lessThan(bottomBoundOfWindow);
});
```

The test fails, it doesn't seem to wait until the element appears (element is scrolled into view in a smooth way). Note that the script itself and the scrollIntoView command are working correctly, because when I a write test like that:

```
.get('#scrollTo')
.wait(1000)
.isInViewport();
```

It passes. However I don't want to use the wait function. I'm new to Cypress, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the same thing happen in ./cypress open as it does in ./cypress run?

Comment: Yes, both in cypress open and run

Answer (score 1):

I think cypress-wait-until needs function `() => cy.get('#scrollTo').isInViewport()` to return something truthy (not sure, the docs are not precise) - but all the examples shown have a false/true return value (false until condition is met).

For your case that may be a simple as

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('isInViewport', { prevSubject: true }, (subject) => {
  ...

  // NO explicit expects here, they will fail and stop the test 
  //expect(bounding.top).to.be.at.least(0);
  //expect(bounding.left).to.be.at.least(0);
  //expect(bounding.right).to.be.lessThan(rightBoundOfWindow);
  //expect(bounding.bottom).to.be.lessThan(bottomBoundOfWindow);

  // Return false or true
  return bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.right < rightBoundOfWindow &&
    bounding.bottom < bottomBoundOfWindow
});
```

Since it's a custom command, you may need to `cy.wrap()`

```js
  // Return false or true
  const result = bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.right < rightBoundOfWindow &&
    bounding.bottom < bottomBoundOfWindow;
  return cy.wrap(result)
```

Comment: Uh when I change it to this, now my test always passes, event if it's not supposed to

Comment: Yeah, `cypress-wait-until` is a bit fiddly - logically, you can do the same with a `.should()`. But your pass with `.wait(1000)` indicates script loading is the main problem. See Bahmutov's [When Can I Start Test](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/) for discussion of similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing the script that scrolls to the element after visiting, then `.should()` will requery with a `defaultCommandTimeout` of `4000` ms. If this is not enough you can alter the timeout for the [specific query](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Timeouts).

```
cy.get('#scrollTo',{ timeout: 6000 }) //sets command timeout to 6 seconds
  .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: But scrollIntoView will make element to be scrolled into view - but in test I want to test if my script which is loaded asynchronously on page (might that be the reason it's not working?) will do that.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. For clarification, are you looking to scrolling to a certain point in the long scroll page to assert whether the element is in the viewport and if not, loop until it does?

Comment: My page loads asynchronously a script, which scrolls page to certain element located at the bottom of long scroll page. I want my test to verify if indeed after visiting page, this element is in viewport (ie. script worked correctly). It doesn't have to be in loop. I used waitUntil cypress plugin because I think that the problem might be smooth scroll, which takes some time.

Comment: In that case, I will update my answer. Since the script should scroll the element into view `.should()` will retry with a default timeout of 4 seconds.

Comment: As far as I know, in cypress "be.visible" is not the same as "is in viewport" - it rather checks if element is rendered on page

Comment: The [`.scrollIntoView()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollintoview#Command-Log) is what you are seeking. It utilizes the [jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) and will animate scrolling to the element is in the view.

Answer (score 0):

So I found solution, I'll post it here just for record in case anyone would have same problem. First I removed my beInViewport function from Cypress custom commands to separate helper function:

```
export function beInViewport($el: any): void {
  const windowInnerWidth = Cypress.config('viewportWidth');
  const windowInnerHeight = Cypress.config('viewportHeight');

  const bounding = $el.get()[0].getBoundingClientRect();

  const rightBoundOfWindow = windowInnerWidth;
  const bottomBoundOfWindow = windowInnerHeight;

  expect(bounding.top).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.left).to.be.at.least(0);
  expect(bounding.right).to.be.lessThan(rightBoundOfWindow);
  expect(bounding.bottom).to.be.lessThan(bottomBoundOfWindow);
}
```

And then I just simply used it as argument passed to `should` function:

```
cy.get('#element').should(beInViewport);
```

Works perfectly.